# C++ error: could not convert pointer to reference (Netbeans)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, netbeans, user-defined-types

Ok, I'm not sure if I named this correctly but here's the problem. I keep trying to pass an array containing user-defined Course objects to a function but it's giving me the error "Could not convert '(Course*)(& courseCatalog)'".
Also, sorry if my code is kinda hard to read. A lot of it is commented out so I can test some stuff.

My main:

```
#include "cc.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool again=1;
    Course c;
    ifstream catalogIn("catalog.dat");
    ofstream catalogOut("catalog.dat");
    Course courseCatalog[256];

    loadInCourses(catalogIn, courseCatalog);

    courseCatalog[getNumCourses(courseCatalog)+1]=addCourse();

    loadOutCourses(catalogOut, courseCatalog);

    return 0;
}
```

My functions:

```
#include "cc.h"

int displayMainMenu(){
  int choice;
  cout<<endl<<"**********MAIN MENU**********"<<endl;
  cout<<"1. Print List Schedule"<<endl;
  cout<<"2. Print Weekly Schedule"<<endl;
  cout<<"3. Get Course"<<endl;
  cout<<"4. Advanced Options"<<endl;
  cout<<"0 to Quit"<<endl;
  cout<<"*****************************"<<endl<<endl;
  cout<<"Menu Choice: ";
  cin>>choice;
  return choice;
}
int displayAdvMenu(){
  int choice;
  cout<<endl<<"**********ADV MENU**********"<<endl;
  cout<<"1. Add Course to Catalog"<<endl;
  cout<<"2. Remove Duplicates"<<endl;
  cout<<"0 to go Back"<<endl;
  cout<<"****************************"<<endl<<endl;
  cout<<"Menu Choice: ";
  cin>>choice;
  return choice;
}

Course addCourse(){
  Course course;

  cout<<"\nCourse name:\t\t";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.getline(course.name, CNAMESIZE);

  cout<<"Course ID:\t\t";
  cin.getline(course.id, CIDSIZE);

  cout<<"Number of credits:\t";
  cin>>course.credits;

  return course;
}

void loadInCourses(ifstream & ifs, Course courseCatalog[]){
    int i=0;
    while(ifs>>courseCatalog[i].credits){
        ifs.getline(courseCatalog[i].name, CNAMESIZE, ',');
        ifs.getline(courseCatalog[i].id, CIDSIZE, ',');
        ifs.getline(courseCatalog[i].professor, CPROFSIZE, ',');
        ifs.getline(courseCatalog[i].semester, CSEMSIZE, ',');
        ifs.get(courseCatalog[i].grade);
        i++;
    }
    return;
}

void loadOutCourses(ofstream & ofs, Course courseCatalog[]){
    for(int i=0; i<=getNumCourses(courseCatalog); i++){
        ofs<<courseCatalog[i].credits<<
             courseCatalog[i].name<<","<<
             courseCatalog[i].id<<","<<
             courseCatalog[i].professor<<","<<
             courseCatalog[i].semester<<","<<
             courseCatalog[i].grade<<endl;   
    }
}

Course findCourse(ifstream & ifs){
    char attribute;
    string needle;
    int credits;
    int name;
    int id;
    bool again=1;
    int numLines = getNumLines(ifs);

    cout<<"Search by (N)ame or (I)d? ";
    cin>>attribute;
    while(again){
        switch(attribute){
            case 'N': case 'n':
                cout<<"Enter name of course: ";
                cin>>name;
                for(int i=0; i<numLines; i++){

                }
                break;
            case 'I': case 'i':
                cout<<"Enter course ID: ";
                cin>>id;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid Attribute. Try Again."<<endl;
        }
    }
}

int getNumCourses(Course courseCatalog[]){
    int numcourses=0;
    for(int i=0;courseCatalog[i].credits!=0;i++){
        numcourses++;
    }
    return numcourses;;
}

int getNumLines(ifstream & ifs){
    char line[1];
    int count=0;

    while(ifs.getline(line, 1)){
        count++;
    }

    ifs.close();
    return count;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Course c){
    os<<endl<<c.name<<endl<<c.id<<endl<<c.credits<<" cr hrs"<<endl;
    return os;
}
```

My header file:

```
#ifndef CC_H
#define CC_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int PREREQ_SIZE = 15;
const int POSTREQ_SIZE = 15;
const int CNAMESIZE=40;
const int CIDSIZE=15;
const int CPROFSIZE=40;
const int CSEMSIZE=15;

struct Course{
  char name[CNAMESIZE];
  char id[CIDSIZE];
  int credits;
  char professor[CPROFSIZE];
  char semester[CSEMSIZE];
  char grade;
  float timeStart;
  float timeStop;
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Course c);
};

Course addCourse();
int displayMainMenu();
int displayAdvMenu();
void printString(Course c);
void loadInCourses(ifstream & ifs, Course courseCatalog);
void loadOutCourses(ofstream & ofs, Course courseCatalog);
Course findCourse(ifstream & ifs);
int getNumCourses(Course courseCatalog[]);
int getNumLines(ifstream & ifs);

#endif
```

UPDATE #1:

```
#include "cc.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool again=1;
    Course c;
    char catalogFilename[128]="catalog.dat";
    ifstream catalogIn(catalogFilename, ios_base::app);
    ofstream catalogOut(catalogFilename, ios_base::app);
    Course courseCatalog[256];

    loadInCourses(catalogIn, courseCatalog);


    courseCatalog[getNumCourses(courseCatalog)+1]=addCourse();

    loadOutCourses(catalogOut, courseCatalog);

    return 0;
}
```

functions:

```
#include "cc.h"

int displayMainMenu(){
  int choice;
  cout<<endl<<"**********MAIN MENU**********"<<endl;
  cout<<"1. Print List Schedule"<<endl;
  cout<<"2. Print Weekly Schedule"<<endl;
  cout<<"3. Get Course"<<endl;
  cout<<"4. Advanced Options"<<endl;
  cout<<"0 to Quit"<<endl;
  cout<<"*****************************"<<endl<<endl;
  cout<<"Menu Choice: ";
  cin>>choice;
  return choice;
}
int displayAdvMenu(){
  int choice;
  cout<<endl<<"**********ADV MENU**********"<<endl;
  cout<<"1. Add Course to Catalog"<<endl;
  cout<<"2. Remove Duplicates"<<endl;
  cout<<"0 to go Back"<<endl;
  cout<<"****************************"<<endl<<endl;
  cout<<"Menu Choice: ";
  cin>>choice;
  return choice;
}

Course addCourse(){
  Course course;

  cout<<"\nCourse name:\t\t";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.getline(course.name, CNAMESIZE);

  cout<<"Course ID:\t\t";
  cin.getline(course.id, CIDSIZE);

  cout<<"Number of credits:\t";
  cin>>course.credits;



  /*<<"Enter semester: ";
  cin.getline(course.semester);

  for(int i=0; i<PREREQ_SIZE && choice==1; i++){
    bool choice;
    cout<<"Add PreReq?: ";
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice==1){
      ...
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i<POSTREQ_SIZE && choice==1; i++){
    bool choice;
    cout<<"Add PostReq?: ";
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice==1){
      ...
    }
  }  */

  return course;
}

void loadInCourses(ifstream & ifs, Course courseCatalog[]){
    cout<<"b*"<<endl<<courseCatalog[0];
    int i=0;
    while(ifs>>courseCatalog[i].credits){
        ifs.getline(courseCatalog[i].name, CNAMESIZE, ',');
        ifs.getline(courseCatalog[i].id, CIDSIZE, ',');
        ifs.getline(courseCatalog[i].professor, CPROFSIZE, ',');
        ifs.getline(courseCatalog[i].semester, CSEMSIZE, ',');
        ifs.get(courseCatalog[i].grade);
        i++;
        cout<<"d*"<<endl<<courseCatalog[i];
    }
    cout<<"c*"<<endl<<courseCatalog[0];    
    return;
}

void loadOutCourses(ofstream & ofs, Course courseCatalog[]){
    for(int i=0; i<=getNumCourses(courseCatalog); i++){
        ofs<<courseCatalog[i].credits<<
             courseCatalog[i].name<<","<<
             courseCatalog[i].id<<","<<
             courseCatalog[i].professor<<","<<
             courseCatalog[i].semester<<","<<
             courseCatalog[i].grade<<endl;   
    }
}

Course findCourse(ifstream & ifs){
    char attribute;
    string needle;
    int credits;
    int name;
    int id;
    bool again=1;
    int numLines = getNumLines(ifs);

    cout<<"Search by (N)ame or (I)d? ";
    cin>>attribute;
    while(again){
        switch(attribute){
            case 'N': case 'n':
                cout<<"Enter name of course: ";
                cin>>name;
                for(int i=0; i<numLines; i++){

                }
                break;
            case 'I': case 'i':
                cout<<"Enter course ID: ";
                cin>>id;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid Attribute. Try Again."<<endl;
        }
    }
}

int getNumCourses(Course courseCatalog[]){
    int numcourses=0;
    for(int i=0;courseCatalog[i].credits!=0;i++){
        numcourses++;
    }
    return numcourses;;
}

int getNumLines(ifstream & ifs){
    char ch;
    int count=0;

    while(ch=ifs.get()){
        count+=(ch=='\n'?1:0);
    }

    ifs.close();
    return count;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Course c){
    os<<endl<<c.name<<endl<<c.id<<endl<<c.credits<<" cr hrs"<<endl;
    return os;
}
```

header:

```
#ifndef CC_H
#define CC_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int PREREQ_SIZE = 15;
const int POSTREQ_SIZE = 15;
const int CNAMESIZE=40;
const int CIDSIZE=15;
const int CPROFSIZE=40;
const int CSEMSIZE=15;

struct Course{
  char name[CNAMESIZE];
  char id[CIDSIZE];
  int credits;
  char professor[CPROFSIZE];
  char semester[CSEMSIZE];
  char grade;
  float timeStart;
  float timeStop;
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Course c);
};

Course addCourse();
int displayMainMenu();
int displayAdvMenu();
void printString(Course c);
void loadInCourses(ifstream & ifs, Course courseCatalog[]);
void loadOutCourses(ofstream & ofs, Course courseCatalog[]);
Course findCourse(ifstream & ifs);
int getNumCourses(Course courseCatalog[]);
int getNumLines(ifstream & ifs);

#endif  /* CC_H */
```

Comment: which line gives an error? for me it [compiles](http://ideone.com/yDqbfy)

Comment: it throws the error in the main file for the loadInCourses and loadOutCourses fns.

Comment: for me it compiles, have you seen link provided above? what is your compiler?

Comment: cygwin on netbeans. what are you using?

Comment: You've got a pretty odd compiler then, privatedata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cc.h`, these lines:

```
void loadInCourses(ifstream & ifs, Course courseCatalog);
void loadOutCourses(ofstream & ofs, Course courseCatalog);
```

should be

```
void loadInCourses(ifstream & ifs, Course courseCatalog[]);
void loadOutCourses(ofstream & ofs, Course courseCatalog[]);
```

Also there is a logic error in `getNumLines`. If the `istream::getline` function fills up its buffer before reaching the end of the line, it doesn't discard the rest of the line. You'll get the rest of the line on subsequent reads.

Instead you could just do `ifs.get()` and count how many `\n` occur.

This function closes `ifs`. It's only called from `findCourse`, and `findCourse` is never called as yet. But when you do call `findCourse`, be aware that you're going to need to rewind the stream back to the start if you want to read the file again (or re-open it).

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip about getNumLines! Do you know much about ifstream? I just recently started using it but whenever i access a file that already has stuff in it, it gets cleared. i tried setting the ifs mode to ios::app but that's not working either. ill upload my updated code...

Comment: `ifstream` should not clear the file, perhaps something else is going on

Comment: perhaps. like i said, i just started using file streaming so i figured i'd check that first

Comment: i added the following code though before loadInCourses() and it doesnt print anything (null) so i figured my problem was in the declaration of the fstreams
    `char line[60];
    catalogIn.getline(line, 60);
    cout<<line;`

Comment: I just noticed that you used the same filename for both files. You shouldn't do that, i.e. have a file open for reading and open for writing at the same time on a different handle. That could explain your symptoms.  Update your code so that only one of those two streams is ever open at any time.

Comment: i'm assuming that by assigning a stream to a file at declaration opens it? is there any way i can assign it but not open it until i need it? or can i just use fstream but change the mode later in the code?

Comment: You can go `ofstream ofs;` and then later `ofs.open("filename");`

Comment: awesome. it's not clearing it now. still got some stuff to sort out but i think i can get it from here. thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your error should have 2 parts, cannot convert from... and to...

You are passing in the From.. and the function signature defines the to...

The two are not the same.  You must change the function signature to match the From being passed in or modify what your passing it to match the To defined by the function prototype.

You will find that reading the entire error is most helpful, and you should probably think that posting the entire error is worth the extra time, since showing us part of it is next to meaningless.  Which will yield you meaningless comments..

If what your after is a function taking a pointer to any array of Course then you should probably call it that :

```
Course (*courseCatalog)[]
```

Or simply :

Course * couseCatalog

Comment: i didn't realize there was more to the error. that's all the ide gave me. i don't want to pass a pointer though, i want to pass the array itself. i'm fairly new to c++ and have not even messed with pointers yet. i want it to all be in array objects.

Comment: Why would you want to copy the entire array?

Comment: You do know that your function declaration signature does not match your function definition signature?

Comment: Ohhh... I didn't. Would that throw that kind of error? I'm away from my computer now so I won't be able to test in for a while

Comment: I'm sure thats your problem.  Fix the header.  I did not realize that you did have the function defined properly.  The declaration is broken.